# How to build custom rich text editor in sitecore including Associated Content Select popup

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, rich-text-editor, sitecore-mvc

I need to modify Rich Text Editor in sitecore to provide a button or something like that to add the Associated Content Select option. Could it be possible and in affirmative answer how to need starting

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Firstly what your trying to achieve does not seems right for me. As associated content(Web Edit Button) sets the datasource of a rendering/sub-layout. you are trying to add that to RTE.

But below is approach you need to take to add a new webEdit button to RTE.

you need to find out what type of RTE you are using for your website. If you have not changed sitecore's default one, you can find it in core database in below path

```
/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Default
```

if you change it you can find the core database item path under this setting in /sitecore/admin/showConfig.aspx

```
<setting name="HtmlEditor.DefaultProfile" value="/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Custom"/>
```

To add a new web edit button you need to create an item with template id ({02404208-46D4-49BF-988B-EB363A52A1C9}) or name WebEdit Button under below path:

```
/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Default/WebEdit Buttons
```

Once you added that you need to fill fields as below:

```
Click: webedit:setdatasource

Type: Datasource Menu
```